# Define a string in Gradle in a non-Android project

Tags: gradle

In Android projects, a "buildConfigField" can be added to build.gradle to define a value that the project's Java code can reference. How can I do this using Gradle in a non-Android Java project? My use case is to define a database endpoint URL that is specific to the developer who is executing the build so that my team's developers don't have to use the same database.

EDIT: The url can be retrieved from the output of a shell script that runs in the build environment.

Comment: You first need to define a way the program should get the information (config file, environment variable, command line parameter, hard coded in the program, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin provides what I was looking for: https://github.com/mfuerstenau/gradle-buildconfig-plugin .